# Observed wavelength of moving distant star (Doppler shift) with hydrogen cloud absorption

Tags: homework-and-exercises, stars, doppler-effect, absorption, redshift

A star is moving away from a stationary observer with known velocity $V_* = 3 \cdot 10^5 m/s$. Between the star and observer, there is a moving hydrogen gas cloud, which is approaching the stationary observer with  known velocity $V_{cloud} = 3 \cdot 10^5 m/s$ and is producing an absorption line in the star's spectrum. What is the wavelength of the absorption line, if the wavelength at rest is 6563 Angström?

Since both the star and the hydrogen cloud move relative to the observer, with different velocities, the doppler shift of the emitted light as perceived by the hydrogen cloud is different from the shift perceived by the stationary observer. This question requires careful consideration of the relative velocities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. Both approaches were wrong. The star is moving away from the cloud and thus all wavelengths get red shifted. If $\lambda_0$ is the wavelength at rest, then the perceived wavelength $\lambda$ is:

$\lambda_0 = \lambda \frac{c + V_o}{c + V_s}(1)$ or $\lambda = \lambda_0 \frac{c + V_s}{c + V_o}(2)$, with $V_s=3 \cdot 10^5 m/s$ and $V_o = -3 \cdot 10^5 m/s$.

On the star reference frame, the emitted $\lambda_0 = 6563$ Angström, is perceived as $\lambda = 6576.15$ Angström (equation $(2)$).

On the cloud reference frame, the perceived wavelength $\lambda=6563$ Angström, is in fact the emitted $\lambda_0 = 6549.87$ Angström of the star (equation $(1)$). That means that the hydrogen cloud, perceives the emitted 6549.87 line as 6563 and it absorbs it.

The remaining spectrum continues through the cloud towards the stationary observer. The perceived wavelength $\lambda_E$ by the stationary observer is different:

$\lambda_E = \lambda_0 \frac{c + V_s}{c+V_o}$, where $V_s = 3 \cdot 10^5$ and $V_o = 0$

The stationary observer perceives the 6549.87 line as red shifted to 6556.43. But since that line is absorbed by the hydrogen cloud, there will be a gap at 6556.43 Angström line in the observers received spectrum.